# Set starting position of marquee text animation

Tags: css, animation, marquee

I would like to use something like this:

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/ywHsk)

```js
$('.marquee').marquee({
  duplicated: true
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
Duplicated option for short length text:
<div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the awesome</div>
```

But I need to set up starting position of this animation to `left: 0;` to see the text immediately. Do you know how to make it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: check the plugin documentation there is already a fix - http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#start-marquee-visible

Answer (score 1):

As Vitorino mentioned, there is already a fix for this on the documentation page for the plugin. 
However, if you for some reason don't want to do that, you can make an inner wrapper on the text with a left value of 97%. It would be something like this:

```
.inner {
    position: relative;
    left: -97%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoXLxm

Answer (score 1):

You must add the startVisible parameter to an object with a value of true.

```
$('.marquee').marquee({ duplicated: true, startVisible: true});
```